# What is the gender-neutral way of saying “gentlemen’s agreement”?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, gender-neutral, gender-politics

How can we refer to a *gentlemen's agreement* in a gender-neutral way in English?

In Spanish we use *palabra de honor* meaning “word of honor”, which carries no assumption about anyone’s sex.

Comment: maybe "scout's honor" ..."on a handshake"?

Comment: palabra de honor is word of honor. Not gentlemen's agreement. And it may or may not have to do with an agreement.

Comment: FWIW, this question helped me find the "bond of manrent," which may be in the wrong direction.

Comment: The term Gentleman's Agreement often has negative connotations referring to unfair agreements between men, as in the [1947 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentleman%27s_Agreement) about antisemitism. Making it gender-neutral loses those associations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A verbal agreement is a phrase you could use; an informal agreement would be another.

Wikipedia defines it as follows:

> A gentlemen's agreement, or gentleman's agreement, is an informal and legally non-binding agreement between two or more parties. It is typically oral, but it may be written or simply understood as part of an unspoken agreement by convention or through mutually-beneficial etiquette.

Its main characteristics are that it’s not legally enforceable, and thus based on trust.

[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentlemen's_agreement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentlemen%27s_agreement) provides details on the use of the term in commerce and trade.

Comment: Verbal agreement seems to have less weight than Gentleman's agreement, it is like there is a social norm that you really have to honor it or else your reputation would be in jeopardy.

Comment: @JacksonPlumber This phrase has really lost, at least in the United States, its gender implications.  People make informal agreements regularly, among both sexes.  Commercially there may be a possibility of a loss of reputation, but probably not widespread, depending on the industry.  E.g., I'll take care of this bill (charge), and you can reimburse me later, or you take care of the next one.  I'll pick the children up Wednesday, you pick them up Thursday etc. If one party fails to often to meet obligations, the parties would cease to make agreements, but it's not widespread.

Comment: Verbal agreements are often legally enforceable. While it is true that *informal agreement* can generally be used as a substitute for *gentlemen's agreement*, it is a rather poor substitute, as it doesn't carry the rich associations of the latter term.

Comment: Agree that "gentlemen's agreement" carries richer associations – especially when one is wanting a phrase that also expresses humor or hyperbole. I landed on this question from a search; was unsatisfied with the suggestion of "informal agreement," then spontaneously used _genteel agreement_ in the context where I  had wanted to use "gentlemen's." Still, there's probably something better to be found.

Answer (score 2):

Resurrecting this as I've had to come up with a good alternative. I've been in discussions that happened to be 3 men, and so using "gentleman's agreement" was not horribly out of line. But I don't want to carry on with it because (1) it sounds archaic regardless and (2) other stakeholders, including women, might become involved.

My best alternatives so far:

- "Honorable parties agreement" maintains the same construction of modifier+"agreement" and is a fairly literal, non-gendered alternative. It's faithful to the original in relying on the implied trustworthiness of each party. It feels a little awkward, but it's a step in the right direction.
- "Mutual trust basis" sounds more natural. It's less faithful to the original in that it expresses the trust each party has in the other, rather than implying inherent trustworthiness in each party. Its meaning is slightly different, but its effect is largely the same.